# StreamReader scoping in exception thrown scenario

Tags: vb.net, exception, streamreader

In the following subroutine, will the `StreamReader` be closed properly when the exception is thrown? Or do I have do something myself to ensure this?

```
Sub mySub()
   Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("someFilename")
   Dim line As String = sr.ReadLine()
   While Not (line Is Nothing)
      ' Some logic here

      If someCondition Then
         Throw New Exception("someExplanation")
      End If

      line = sr.ReadLine()
   End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the StreamReader variable in a using statement.

```
Using sr as StreamReader = File.OpenText("someFilename")
...
End Using
```

Comment: If I throw an exception from within `...`, the `StreamReader` and file handles etc will be closed?

Comment: It will automatically call .Dispose() on the StreamReader once execution leaves the Using block, which releases all resources used by the StreamReader / underlying stream.

Comment: Ace, thanks. I wonder why that doesn't occur anyway when leaving the enclosing function scope? Nothing else holds a reference to it.

Comment: @Tomalak, it will happen eventually when the garbage collector gets around to it, but potentially not before you need the file again.

Answer (score 1):

Stream won't be closed until the process is terminated. Even it does you should close it. Best way is to use "using" method as it mentioned before. But it doesn't cause data loss unlike while writing it does. In other translation, you should close the Stream, but it's not critic.